# Convert varchar list to int in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I need a way to have the @listOfPageIds be recognized as a list of numbers instead of strings. I have tried casting, removing the single quotes... I really don't want to do a loop in sql.

```
Declare @listOfPageIds varchar(50) ;

Set @listofPageIds = '2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 14, 15';

select * from mytable p where p.PageId in( @listOfPageIds);
```

Comment: You can't use a variable like that. You have to either parse out your list with a splitter or use dynamic sql. Would it be possible to use a user defined table type instead of a csv list of values?

Comment: No matter what, a list is a string. If you need those as numbers, then you'll have to split them into separate rows.

Comment: Did you search SO for anything related to separating CSV (comma separated values) in TSQL?

Comment: I did... I wasn't wanting to split on the delimiter, but apparently I have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well on production server I'd write some table valued function for splitting lists, but if you need quick ad-hoc query, this xml trick could work

```
declare @listOfPageIds varchar(50), @data xml
declare @temp table(id int)

select @listofPageIds = '2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 14, 15';
select @data = '<t>' + replace(@listofPageIds, ', ', '</t><t>') + '</t>'

insert into @temp
select
    t.c.value('.', 'int') as id
from @data.nodes('t') as t(c)

select * from @temp
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4059)</kbd>**

Comment: just wanted to add that if your list of values do not contain a space after each comma like  
`select @listofPageIds = '2,3,4,5, 6, 7,14,15';`
you will receive a sql conversion error. The following will fix that  
`SET @listofPageIds = replace(@listofPageIds, ' ', '')`
 `SELECT @data = '<t>' + replace(@listofPageIds, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>'`

Answer (score 1):

### DECLARE @YourTable

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (col1 INT);
INSERT INTO @yourTable VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15);
```

### Dynamic SQL Solution

```
DECLARE @listOfPageIds nvarchar(255);
SET @listOfPageIds = '2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 14, 15'
EXEC
(
'
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (col1 INT);
INSERT INTO @yourTable VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
SELECT *
FROM @yourTable
WHERE col1 IN (' + @listOfPageIds+ ')'
)
```

### Recursive CTE Solution

```
DECLARE @listOfPageIds nvarchar(255);
SET @listOfPageIds = '2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 14, 15'
SET @listOfPageIds = REPLACE(@listOfPageIds,' ','') + ',';  -- Put the end comma there instead of having to use a case statement in my query
                                                            -- As well as getting rid of useless white space with REPLACE()

WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 1 row_count, CAST(SUBSTRING(@listOfPageIds,0,CHARINDEX(N',',@listOfPageIds,0)) AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS search_val, CHARINDEX(',',@listOfPageIds,0) + 1 AS starting_position
    UNION ALL
    SELECT row_count + 1,CAST(SUBSTRING(@listOfPageIds,starting_position,CHARINDEX(',',@listOfPageIds,starting_position) - starting_position) AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS search_val, CHARINDEX(',',@listOfPageIds,starting_position) + 1 AS starting_position
    FROM CTE
    WHERE row_count < (LEN(@listOfPageIds) - LEN(REPLACE(@listOfPageIds,',','')))
)

SELECT *
FROM @yourTable
WHERE col1 IN (SELECT CAST(search_val AS INT) FROM CTE)
```

Results(@yourTable has values 1-15):

```
col1
-----------
2
3
4
5
6
7
14
15
```

Comment: It might be helpful if voters commented on what this answer is so lacking that it deserves down votes.

Comment: I don't know. The OP said he didn't want to loop but recursive solutions aren't loops. So I don't know.

Comment: Actually a recursive cte that is used for counting like this is the same thing as a loop behind the scenes. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/ Add to that the solution you posted doesn't return the data the OP is looking for probably doesn't help either.

Comment: well i ended up having to use a similar solution to both answers and that format of having to loop through and return as a table is the right answer. I was ignorant that it could not be done simply without this recursion. :) Both answers are fine.