# How to convert varchar containing list of uniqueidentifiers into a list of uniqueidentifiers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

In the query data type of employeeId column is `uniqueidentifier`. I am getting following error while executing

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

```
declare @tt nvarchar = 'e347d817-3121-e811-9c0b-58fb847a6047,e447d817-3121-e811-9c0b-58fb847a6047,e147d817-3121-e811-9c0b-58fb847a6047,df47d817-3121-e811-9c0b-58fb847a6047,de47d817-3121-e811-9c0b-58fb847a6047,e547d817-3121-e811-9c0b-58fb847a6047,e247d817-3121-e811-9c0b-58fb847a6047,e047d817-3121-e811-9c0b-58fb847a6047,dd47d817-3121-e811-9c0b-58fb847a6047'

select * 
from [dbo].[employee] 
where [employeeId] in (@tt)
```

How can I convert the string of uniqueidentifiers (GUIDs) to list of uniqueidentifiers?

I had tried to perform the conversion as shown in
[Convert varchar list to int in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680931/convert-varchar-list-to-int-in-sql-server)
but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--Create this function.  This function will convert string to Id as row
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StrParse]
               (@delimiter CHAR(1),  
                @csv       NTEXT)  
RETURNS @tbl TABLE(Keys  NVARCHAR(255))  
AS  

  BEGIN  
    DECLARE  @len INT  
    SET @len = Datalength(@csv)  
    IF NOT @len > 0  
      RETURN  

    DECLARE  @l INT  
    DECLARE  @m INT  

    SET @l = 0  
    SET @m = 0  

    DECLARE  @s VARCHAR(255)  
    DECLARE  @slen INT  

    WHILE @l <= @len  
      BEGIN  

        SET @l = @m + 1--current position  
        SET @m = Charindex(@delimiter,Substring(@csv,@l + 1,255))--next delimiter or 0  

        IF @m <> 0  
          SET @m = @m + @l  
        --insert @tbl(keys) values(@m)  
        SELECT @slen = CASE   
                         WHEN @m = 0 THEN 255 --returns the remainder of the string  
                         ELSE @m - @l  
                       END --returns number of characters up to next delimiter  

        IF @slen > 0  
          BEGIN  
            SET @s = Substring(@csv,@l,@slen)  
            INSERT INTO @tbl  
                       (Keys)  
            SELECT @s  
          END  

        SELECT @l = CASE   
                      WHEN @m = 0 THEN @len + 1 --breaks the loop  
                      ELSE @m + 1  
                    END --sets current position to 1 after next delimiter  
      END  

    RETURN  
  END
go

--Below code will return the value you are expecting
declare @tt nvarchar (MAX) = 'e347d817-3121-e811-9c0b-58fb847a6047,e447d817-3121-e811-9c0b-58fb847a6047'
select * 
from [dbo].[employee]
where [employeeId] in (select keys from dbo.StrParse (',', @tt))
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  I still get the same conversion error when running the select statement with the `dbo.StrParse` function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you declare your variable like this:

```
declare @tt nvarchar
```

you get a string of **exactly ONE character** in length!

You should ***ALWAYS*** (no exceptions!) define an explicit **length** for your `varchar` (and `nvarchar`) variables:

```
declare @tt nvarchar(2000) = .....
```

Also - if you define a `nvarchar` as a Unicode string, you **must** prefix the string literal you assign to it with a `N` to make it a Unicode string literal:

```
declare @tt nvarchar(2000) = N'.......'
```

But in the end, even that is *not* going to work - because the `IN` operator expects a **list of something** - not a single string ..... You should declare a table variable, insert your values into that table variable, and then do the select:

```
DECLARE @tt TABLE (ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

INSERT INTO @tt(ID)
VALUES ('e347d817-3121-e811-9c0b-58fb847a6047'), 
       ('e447d817-3121-e811-9c0b-58fb847a6047'),
       etc. 

SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[employee] 
WHERE [employeeId] IN (SELECT ID FROM @tt)
```

Comment: hi marc_s, even after converting it to declare @tt nvarchar(2000) it returns only 1 unique identifier. other values get truncated

Comment: @AbhishekPandey: read my whole answer - you **cannot** use a single string in a `IN` operator - I do show a solution for this - try it!

Comment: I am getting a single string of GUIDs as a parametter so I don't convert it  into a table. And I want to convert it from a string to table

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic SQL to achieve that:

```
--declare string, that will hold your query
declare @query varchar(4000) = 'select * 
                                from [dbo].[employee] 
                                where [employeeId] in '
--transform your list of IDs to list of values suitable for a where clause
set @tt = '(''' + replace(@tt, ',', ''',''') + ''')'
set @query = @query + @tt
--execute the query
exec(@query)
```